# TSQL Merge Slow After First Success Index Issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge, sql-server-2022

Using MSSQL 2022.

Source temp table has 156,289 rows. Destination table has zero rows. Use case is to insert rows from temp->destination where rows do not already exist in destination. 4 columns determine if a row is unique.

Using Merge When Not Matched by Target, the first time code is run it takes less than 10 seconds to complete, inserting 156,289. The second time it is run, it takes ~8 minutes to complete, inserting zero rows. The behavior is correct but it takes a very long time. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H7Cmfrd2n shows a 440mb memory grant and estimated rows 358,028 even though zero are written the second time.

Using Insert Where Not Exists, the the first time code is run it takes less than 10 seconds to complete, inserting 156,289. The second time it is run, it again takes a few seconds to complete, inserting zero rows. The behavior is correct and performs acceptably. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyQ8fdu27 shows no memory grant and estimates 156,289 rows even though zero are written the second time.

```
Create Table #InputInterimTags ( AspectKey VarChar(400) , AspectValue VarChar(400) , InputInterimId Int , Tpid Int )
Create Clustered Index #InputInterimTags_Pk On #InputInterimTags (Tpid,AspectKey,AspectValue)
... temp table is populated...
Update Statistics #InputInterimTags With Fullscan
Create Table dbo.Aspects
  (
        AspectsId Int Identity(9,1) Primary Key
      , RowStampUtc Datetime2(7) 
      , DictAspectsId Int 
      , AspectKey VarChar(400)
      , AspectValue VarChar(400)
      , DictAspectsAssociationStatesId Int
      , Tpid BigInt 
  )
Create Index Aspects_Ix01 On dbo.Aspects (Tpid,AspectKey,AspectValue) Include (DictAspectsId)
```

Have tried different combinations of composite and single indexes on Aspects table, collation, additional filtering.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you compared the good and poor query execution plans? Please include the actual execution plan (paste the plan)

Comment: What's the actual code look like? `#tmptmp` doesn't have a `fkid` column so `CREATE INDEX #tmptmpix01 ON #tmptmp (aspkey, aspvalue, fkid, rootid)` would generate an error.

Comment: You mention that "this" code is executed multiple times, one assumes that you're dropping and recreating the temp table to do this. Given that SQL Server can trip you up by caching statistics on temp table indexes are you creating statistics `WITH FULLSCAN` on the `#tmptmpix01` index in each iteration?

Comment: `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX dtix0 ON desttable (fkid, aspkey, aspvalue, rootid)` and the same for the other table. Also `AND (LEN(ISNULL(dbSrc.aspkey, '')) > 0)` can be simplified to `AND dbSrc.aspkey > ''`

Comment: Perhaps it's time to re-think the solution design to your use case. To avoid duplicates: Do you actually need the temp table and/or do you really need merge?

Comment: We need to see the query plans ourselves otherwise we can't help. Please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface thanks, will get something over there. Also editing original content again because I have found that Insert Into Where Not Exists is performant while Merge is not.

Comment: @Stu  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1CnFrd2n  and https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyQAFBu22 show the differences in plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- The `MERGE` is unnecessary. As you have noted, you can just use `INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS`. But you don't need to, and should not, re-join `#InputInterimTags` in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery.
- Because both indexes are not declared `UNIQUE`, you are getting a many-to-many Merge Join in the plan, which is rather inefficient, and makes the server want to add a Spool as well.
- A side note: an `EXISTS` subquery does not need to select anything, it can just `SELECT 1`.

```sql
Create Table #InputInterimTags ( AspectKey VarChar(400) , AspectValue VarChar(400) , InputInterimId Int , Tpid Int )
Create UNIQUE Clustered Index #InputInterimTags_Pk On #InputInterimTags (Tpid,AspectKey,AspectValue)
... temp table is populated...
Update Statistics #InputInterimTags With Fullscan
Create Table dbo.Aspects
  (
        AspectsId Int Identity(9,1) Primary Key
      , RowStampUtc Datetime2(7) 
      , DictAspectsId Int 
      , AspectKey VarChar(400)
      , AspectValue VarChar(400)
      , DictAspectsAssociationStatesId Int
      , Tpid BigInt 
  )
Create UNIQUE Index Aspects_Ix01 On dbo.Aspects (Tpid,AspectKey,AspectValue) Include (DictAspectsId)
```

You may want to consider making `Aspects_Ix01 On dbo.Aspects` a clustered index, and its primary key non-clustered, depending on your use case.

Then your insert should be like this.

```
INSERT INTO Aspects (
  DictAspectsId, AspectKey, AspectValue, DictAspectsAssociationStatesId, Tpid
)
SELECT
  1,
  iit.AspectKey,
  iit.AspectValue,
  1,
  iit.Tpid
FROM #InputInterimTags iit WITH (TABLOCK) -- might as well tablock for performance as it's a temp table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Aspects asp
    WHERE asp.Tpid = iit.Tpid
      AND asp.AspectKey = iit.AspectKey
      AND asp.AspectValue = iit.AspectValue
      AND asp.DictAspectsId = 1
);
```

Consider using `TABLOCK` on the inserted table also, assuming you are not worried about blocking anyone else.

Comment: Thanks! First run takes ~5 seconds and subsequent runs take ~3 seconds consistently. Appreciate the help.